# Expose limited method from specific API : WSO2 API Manager Version 2.6.0 free

Tags: wso2

I want to expose limited methods from my micoservice to outside.

I have 2 applications, each of one have its own access token (App1 and App2). Able to subscribe API with all methods to App1.
Want to subscribe same api with limited method's(not all methods) to App2.

Example : App1 ---subscribe ---X microservice (X having 2 post method's)
App2 ---subscribe ---X microservice should expose only one method from out of 2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using scopes.

Let's say you have an API with the following resources and respective scopes.

- /check-status
- /upload-photo
- /upload-file

Then you can create 2 scopes as read and write. The read scope is attached to read role and write scope is attached to write role.

Apply the scopes to resources as follows.

- /check-status  : read
- /upload-photo. : write
- /upload-file.  : write

In the devportal, when a user1(with read role) logs in, he can create an app and subscribe to the API. When generating an access token he will get only the read scope. He will see both the scopes. But the request is protected with the scope. So users with that scope only can access that particular resource.

Refer - https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/01/article-an-overview-of-scope-management-with-wso2-api-manager/

Comment: Thanks Pubci , but I want expose /check-status to app1 and for app2 want to expose all resources  /check-status ,/upload-photo and /check-status . I can see one scope per resource . May be for APP3 will expose  only 2  /check-status ,/upload-photo

Comment: Yes, one scope per resource. If you want an app to have all 3 resources, then the user should have all 3 scopes. Basically, users should have 3 roles.